# Oracle-11g SQL command line closing automatically in windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When I open the "Run SQL Command Line" in windows(Start->Programs->Oracle-11g->Run SQL Command Line) it is closing automatically. I am not able to figure out why it is happening. Please help me about this issue.

Comment: Open a regular command line window and run `sqlplus` from within that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start sqlplus from the command line, like in *Nix. To do this make sure that you know where your Oracle executables are. The are in a ORACLE_HOME\bin\ directory. ORACLE_HOME can be anywhere on your disks.

1. set ORACLE_HOME=c:\where\you\put\it
2. set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

Now you can start sqlplus and see what happens.

Comment: Did you use the commandline ? Did the assignments of the values to the ORACLE_HOME and PATH variables work ? Where is sqlplus.exe located? (I have no windows so I could not check the exact assignment syntax for the commandline tool in windows)

Comment: could you explain in more steps

Answer (score 0):

There is SQL*Plus in Oracle package, which you may use for input sql commands